# Sort Search API results by taxonomy reference field name (and not TID)

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, search

I have a views index page that when displaying results without a text search I want to display sorted alphabetically by a taxonomy reference fields name. I can get it to sort by this reference field using the Search API Sort module, but it sorts by the term ID instead of based on the term name. I've also tried to do the same using Views sorting but it doesn't work. I tried creating a relationship to the term in Views but it wouldn't let me sort by fields added via that relationship.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: To be able to sort by a field in search API, you need to add it to the index.

Comment: It is in the index... the problem is that since its a taxonomy field its sorting by the TID and not the name.

Comment: Sorry, I probably wasn't clear. The taxonomy NAME has to be in the index. I can't recall offhand the exact steps to do this which is why this is a comment and not an answer.